# Kivy RecycleBoxLayout change font color

Tags: python, kivy

I have been unable to find a way to change the font color for kivy recyclebox. How do I change the label properties? Below is my code.

Python side:

```
class ExampleViewer(RecycleView): 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super(ExampleViewer, self).__init__(**kwargs) 
        self.data = [{'text': f"[color=[0,0,0,1]]{x}[/color]"} for x in range(20)]
```

Kivy Side:

```
ExampleViewer: 
    viewclass: 'Label'  # defines the viewtype for the data items. 
    orientation: "vertical"
  
    RecycleBoxLayout: 
        color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        markup: True 
  
        # defines the size of the widget in reference to width and height 
        default_size_hint: 1, None 
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height 
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

I've tried creating a markup for the label and changing the color directly. Neither method has worked for me. Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to change the colour of a text in Label widget is to specific the attibute, *color*.

### Snippets

```
self.data = [{'text': str(x), 'color': [1, 0, 1, 1]} for x in range(20)]
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

Builder.load_string('''
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x), 'color': [1, 0, 1, 1]} for x in range(100)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: RecycleView - Label's text is pink colour]